# Parameter by reference in a lambda expression in C# and Microsoft Fakes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, unit-testing, lambda

I am new to the Microsoft Fakes framework and am attempting to Shim some standard, older ADO.NET code to bypass the database connection altogether for my unit test.  I have successfully Shim'd SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter (via DbDataAdapter) and am attempting to fake the Fill(DataSet) method on the data adapter.  All seems to be working well expect after my fake Fill runs, which manually adds a table to the dataset, the code under test does not seem to see the dataset I created.  It's as if the dataset object is being passed by value and not by reference.

Here is the code under test (VB.NET):

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(DB("CIMS"))
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim ds As New DataSet
...
Dim da as New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(ds)
```

And here is the unit test (C#):

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    // arrange
     ShimSqlConnection.ConstructorString = (@this, connectionString) => new ShimSqlConnection();
    ShimSqlCommand.Constructor = (@this) => new ShimSqlCommand();
    ShimSqlConnection.AllInstances.Open = (@this) => { };
    ShimSqlConnection.AllInstances.Close = (@this) => { };
    ShimDbDataAdapter.AllInstances.FillDataSet = (DbDataAdapter @this, DataSet dataset) =>
    {
        dataset = new System.Data.DataSet();
        dataset.Tables.Add();
        return 0;
    };
...
```

When debugging this test, code flow enters the faked FillDataSet function just fine, the dataset gets the table added but after exiting the function, the dataset referenced by ds shows 0 tables in the table collection.  I have also tried setting the DataSetName property, which it takes in the test expression by the code under test never sees the new name.

For now, converting en-masse our entire application to a more modern data access tech is not practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I no longer require an answer to this question. I removed the line `dataset = new System.Data.DataSet()` from my fake Fill method (.FakeDataSet) and all is well. I guess I was overwriting the dataset passed by reference with a new one and as expected that one is not accessible to the calling code.